# Ember - Custom Computed Property to check if all dependent fields exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

I am creating a form and I am trying to find a simple, elegant way of handling to see if all inputs exist.

```
Form = Ember.Object.extend({
  // section 1
  name: null,
  age: null,
  isABoolean: null,

  // section 2
  job: null,
  numberOfSiblings: null,

  isComplete: Ember.computed.and('_isSection1Complete', '_isSection2Complete'),

  _isSection1Complete: function() {
    var isPresent = Ember.isPresent;
    return isPresent(this.get('name')) && isPresent(this.get('age')) && isPresent(this.get('isABoolean'));
  }.property('name', 'age', 'isABoolean'),

  _isSection2Complete: function() {
    var isPresent = Ember.isPresent;
    return isPresent(this.get('job')) && isPresent(this.get('numberOfSiblings'));
  }.property('job', 'numberOfSiblings')
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to scale. My actual application will have many sections (over 20 sections).

I am looking into trying to create a re-usable computed property that fits my needs. Take for example the code of what I am going for:

```
Form = Ember.Object.extend({
  // properties...

  isComplete: Ember.computed.and('_isSection1Complete', '_isSection2Complete'),

  _isSection1Complete: Ember.computed.allPresent('name', 'age', 'isABoolean'),

  _isSection2Complete: Ember.computed.allPresent('job', 'numberOfSiblings')
});
```

I feel that this is a common case, but I'm failing to find the correct computed properties on how to execute this, so I would like to make my own.

Two questions:

1. Where's the best place to define the custom computed property? Can I just attach a function to `Ember.computed`?
2. Is there an easier way to solve this? I feel like I'm overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make a minor adjustment to Evan's solution, but this works perfectly for anyone else that needs it:

```
App.computed = {
  allPresent: function () {
    var propertyNames = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    var computedArgs = propertyNames.slice(0); // copy the array

    computedArgs.push(function () {
      return propertyNames.map(function (propertyName) {
        // get the value for each property name
        return this.get(propertyName);
      }, this).every(Ember.isPresent);
    });

    return Ember.computed.apply(Ember.computed, computedArgs);
  }
};
```

This can now be used as such:

```
_isSection2Complete: App.computed.allPresent('job', 'numberOfSiblings')
```

Answer (score 3):

As for Question #1,

You can define a custom computed helper in the `App` namespace. In this example, I created a new computed helper called `allPresent` that checks each property passed in against `Ember.isPresent`.

```js
App.computed = {
  allPresent: function (propertyNames) {
    // copy the array
    var computedArgs = propertyNames.slice(0);

    computedArgs.push(function () {
      return propertyNames.map(function (propertyName) {
        // get the value for each property name
        return this.get(propertyName);
      }, this).every(Ember.isPresent);
    });

    return Ember.computed.apply(Ember.computed, computedArgs);
  }
};
```

It can be used like this, per your example code:

```js
_isSection2Complete: App.computed.allPresent(['job', 'numberOfSiblings'])
```

I adapted this from the approach here: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/custom-ember-computed-properties

As for Question #2, I can't think of a simpler solution.

Comment: Will this work if the property exists but has a value of `false`?

Comment: The `allPresent` helper uses `Ember.isPresent`, and so it follows the same semantics. `Ember.isPresent(false)` returns `true`, so it works in that sense.